# How do I generate connected shapes into a given volume?

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: blender model]I'm an amateur 3d modeler / printer who's been using Blender "the hard way" for years and I'm just scratching the surface on geometry nodes and such.  I'm trying to develop a model of a character whose legs are essentially a bunch of tentacles twisted into the shapes of humanoid limbs, with some gaps in between to emphasize that it has no bones in there.  I've struggled to model all this manually and twist the tentacles along paths.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this?[image: mush standee]
[image: mush portrait]

Comment: i highly recommend adding images how it should look like and at least a blend file with a "try" you made, so it doesn't have the feeling of "i am searching for someone who does my work"

Answer (score 0):

You should watch this video, learn this concept, and add your creativity and research to make your version.

[image]